# Create and Join Temporary Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I am looking for some assistance in joining two temporary tables for a final output.

I have to create different tables one to calculate time spent and the other calculating a total sum

unfortunately i couldn't do this in one table as there were a lot of duplicate time values causing the wrong calculations.

below is the code:

---

```
CREATE TABLE KPI_REPORT (
    USERNAME      CHAR(50),
    HOURS         NUMBER(10),
    MINUTES       NUMBER(10),
    TOTAL_CTN     NUMBER(10),
    AVERAGE_CTN   NUMBER(10)
);

CREATE TABLE TOTAL_TIME (
    USERNAME   CHAR(50),
    HOURS      NUMBER(10),
    MINUTES    NUMBER(10)
);

CREATE TABLE TOTAL_CARTONS (
    USERNAME    CHAR(50),
    TOTAL_CTN   NUMBER(10)
);
    INSERT INTO Total_Time ( Username, Hours, Minutes )
    select 
        ia.username --username
        ,ROUND( SUM( ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1 ) * 24,2 ) --hours
        ,ROUND( SUM( ( ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1 ) * 24 ) * 60,2 ) --minutes
    from 
        actual_db_1 ia
    where 
        to_char( ia.dtime3, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) between '2019-01-08' and '2019-01-08'
        and ia.site = '7'
        and ia.from_location = 'ORDERPICK'
        and ia.queue like 'LL%'
    group by
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;

    INSERT INTO Total_Cartons ( Username, Total_Ctn )
    select
        ia.USERNAME --username
        ,SUM( pm.qty/pm.packfactor_1 ) --cartons
    from 
        actual_db_1 ia, 
        actual_db_2 pm
    where 
        to_char( ia.dtime3, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) between '2019-01-08' and '2019-01-08'
        and ia.site = '7'
        and ia.queue like 'LL%'
        and pm.code = product
    group by 
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;

    INSERT INTO KPI_Report ( Username, Hours, Minutes, Total_Ctn, Average_Ctn )

    select
        Total_Time.Username
        ,Total_Time.Hours
        ,Total_Time.Minutes
        ,Total_Cartons.Total_Ctn
        ,ROUND( ( SUM( ia.qty/pm.packfactor_1 ) )  / ( SUM( ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1) * 24 ),2 )
    from 
        Total_Time
        ,Total_Cartons
    where 
        Total_Time.Username = Total_Cartons.Username 
    group by
       Total_Time.Username 
       ,Total_Time.Hours
       ,Total_Time.Minutes
       ,Total_Cartons.Total_Ctn
    order by
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;
```

---

Appreciate any help on this as i am stuck.

Comment: Intermediate tables come with a high overhead of writing to and reading from disk. (And as these are not true temporary tables have the additional overhead of clearing out the persisted records prior to reuse.) Have you tested just querying the underlying tables and joining the result sets?

Comment: Beyond that you should post some sample input data and sample output i.e. desired content of `KPI_Report` derived from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You must, add tables `actual_db_1`, `actual_db_2` to query

```
CREATE TABLE KPI_REPORT (
    USERNAME      CHAR(50),
    HOURS         NUMBER(10),
    MINUTES       NUMBER(10),
    TOTAL_CTN     NUMBER(10),
    AVERAGE_CTN   NUMBER(10)
);

CREATE TABLE TOTAL_TIME (
    USERNAME   CHAR(50),
    HOURS      NUMBER(10),
    MINUTES    NUMBER(10)
);

CREATE TABLE TOTAL_CARTONS (
    USERNAME    CHAR(50),
    TOTAL_CTN   NUMBER(10)
);
    INSERT INTO Total_Time ( Username, Hours, Minutes )
    select 
        ia.username --username
        ,ROUND( SUM(ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1 ) * 24,2 ) --hours
        ,ROUND( SUM( ( ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1 ) * 24 ) * 60,2 ) --minutes
    from 
        actual_db_1 ia
    where 
        to_char( ia.dtime3, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) between '2019-01-08' and '2019-01-08'
        and ia.site = '7'
        and ia.from_location = 'ORDERPICK'
        and ia.queue like 'LL%'
    group by
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;

    INSERT INTO Total_Cartons ( Username, Total_Ctn )
    select
        ia.USERNAME --username
        ,SUM( pm.qty/pm.packfactor_1 ) --cartons
    from 
        actual_db_1 ia, 
        actual_db_2 pm
    where 
        to_char( ia.dtime3, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) between '2019-01-08' and '2019-01-08'
        and ia.site = '7'
        and ia.queue like 'LL%'
        and pm.code = product
    group by 
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;

    INSERT INTO KPI_Report ( Username, Hours, Minutes, Total_Ctn, Average_Ctn )

    select
        Total_Time.Username
        ,Total_Time.Hours
        ,Total_Time.Minutes
        ,Total_Cartons.Total_Ctn
        ,ROUND( ( SUM( ia.qty/pm.packfactor_1 ) )  / ( SUM( ia.dtime3-ia.dtime1) * 24 ),2 )
    from 
        Total_Time
        INNER JOIN Total_Cartons ON Total_Time.Username = Total_Cartons.Username
        INNER JOIN actual_db_1 ia ON ia.username = Total_Time.Username
        INNER JOIN actual_db_2 pm ON ia.product = pm.code

    group by
       Total_Time.Username 
       ,Total_Time.Hours
       ,Total_Time.Minutes
       ,Total_Cartons.Total_Ctn
    order by
        ia.username;

    COMMIT;
```

Comment: Surely the OP's aim in using intermediate tables `Total_Time` and `Total_Cartons` is to avoid the referencing of actual tables. How does this help them?